# Knockout sortable array not displaying nested elements correctly

Tags: javascript, jquery, knockout.js, jquery-ui-sortable, knockout-sortable

I'm new to Knockout.js, and recently I've started working with JQuery and the knockout-sortable project. For my project, I'm using a complex data structure to display some forms. At one point, I'm trying to make a nested sortable array of pages that contain questions. I am able to get a container that holds all of the pages and their information, but I am having trouble getting the container to show the questions correctly.

I the following is in the HTML:

```
                <h2><span data-bind="text: DiscoveryFormUpdateLabel"></span></h2>
                <div class="pagesList" data-bind="foreach:discoveryForm">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="text-area">
                            <label>Discovery Form Name: </label>
                            <input data-bind="value:Name" width="400" />
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <br />
                    <br />
                    <br />
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="text-area">
                            <label>Welcome (HTML):</label>
                            <textarea data-bind="value: Welcome" rows="12" cols="89"></textarea>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <ul data-bind="sortable: {template: 'pages', data:discoveryFormPages}"></ul>

                 <script type="text/html" id="pages">
                    <li>
                        <div class="row">
                            <label>Name: </label>
                            <input data-bind="value:Name" />
                        </div>

                        <div class="row">
                            <label>Questions:</label>
                        </div>

                        <ul data-bind="sortable: {foreach:Questions}">
                            <li>Foo</li>
                        </ul>

                        <ul data-bind="foreach:Questions">
                            <li>Foo</li>
                        </ul>

                        <ul data-bind="sortable: { template: 'questions', foreach:Questions}" width="80%"></ul>
                    </li>
                </script>

                <script type="text/html" id="questions">
                    <li>
                        <div class="row">
                            <label>Subject:</label>
                            <textarea data-bind="value:Subject" cols="45"></textarea>
                        </div>
                        <div class="row">
                            <label>Type:</label>
                            <select data-bind="options: $root.questionTypes, optionsText:'Description', value:Type"></select>
                        </div>
                        <div class="row">
                            <label>Tagline:</label>
                            <textarea data-bind="value: Tagline" cols="45"></textarea>
                        </div>
                        <div class="row">
                            <label>Visible:</label>
                            <input type="checkbox" data-bind="checked:Visible" />
                        </div>
                    </li>
                </script>
```

In the `pages` template, I use three different ways of trying to display the questions. The first method displays one sortable `Foo`, the second one displays the correct number of `Foo`s, and the third one displays a blank sortable area with no items. I am working on a JS Fiddle, but I have to get the complex information from the database, so it's taking time. Any help there would also be welcome :).

My question, then, is why am I getting three different things, and where am I going wrong?

EDIT: I based my templates off of [this](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/template-binding.html).

I'm using [this](https://github.com/rniemeyer/knockout-sortable) project.

I envision the end result being somewhat similar to [this](http://jsfiddle.net/rniemeyer/uhZEL/).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It might help to get a sample in jsFiddle, but it looks like:

For this one: `<ul data-bind="sortable: {foreach:Questions}">`

You want either just `sortable: Questions` which is equivalent to `sortable { data: questions }`

For this one: `<ul data-bind="sortable: { template: 'questions', foreach:Questions}" width="80%"></ul>`

You want: `sortable: { template: 'questions', data: Questions }`

So, mainly just using `data` instead of `foreach`

Comment: Wow, I'm a noob. That completely fixed it. Thanks!